# MSBuild error - Unknown switch. Switch: /bl:MonoDevelop.binlog

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, monodevelop

I was trying to build the monodevelop source from https://github.com/mono/monodevelop using MSBuild

While building however the process stops with the error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /bl:MonoDevelop.binlog
```

Here is the line from the winbuild.bat file which is causing the problem

```
"%MSBUILD_EXE%" Main.sln /bl:MonoDevelop.binlog /m "/p:Configuration=%CONFIG%" "/p:Platform=%PLATFORM%" %* || goto :error
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition 15.2 (26430.14) running on Windows 10 Home

I can't seem to figure what's causing this issue. Google hasn't helped either. I hope someone over here can help me figure this out.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured this out. I read somewhere that the bl switch is supported only on version MSBuild version15.3 and after. Mine seems to be lower than this.I'll try updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Visual Studio to a recent version.

Binary logs have been introduced in MSBuild 15.3, with a few bugfixes in later versions.

The current VS and MSBuild versions are 15.6.*, make sure you update to the latest versions of the tools.

Comment: Yup, thanks. Doing this right now. I'll let you know how this goes.

Comment: That did it! Thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the switch ('/bl:MonoDevelop.binlog') is ? Are you using this switch for any reason ? If you don't have the answer comment/remove the switch and run the MS Build.

Maybe MS Build don't know why this switch is!